# Python - Is there any way to access, from within a method, the class to which it is attached?

Tags: python, class, methods

In Python, if I define a method within a class, I can access the containing class using `__class__`:

```
>>> class A:
...     def f(self):
...         print(__class__)
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> B().f()
<class '__main__.A'>
```

However, if I define the method outside the class and then attach it to the class, `__class__` is unavailable:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> def f(self):
...     print(__class__)
... 
>>> A.f = f
>>> class B(A): 
...     pass
... 
>>> B().f()
NameError: name '__class__' is not defined
```

In this second scenario, is there any way to access, from within the method `f`, the class `A` to which it is attached?

Comment: I believe `A().f()` produces the same error... The closure of `f` has no `__class__` at all.

Comment: You're thinking of `self.__class__`. That actually works in both cases.

Comment: @kindall - Unfortunately, `self.__class__` doesn't give the result I'm looking for. It returns `B`, the class of the object `B()` on which `f` is invoked, rather than `A`, the class to which `f` is attached.

Comment: Overall this sounds complex and like you may be re-implementing most of the Python class machinery.  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: `__class__` is the class a method was defined in, regardless of what class (if any, or how many classes) the method appears in the `__dict__` of. Attaching a function to a new class has no effect on `__class__`.

Comment: Why do you need to access the parent class's name? Anyways, you can check `B`'s method resolution order with `B.mro()` and aside from the final one which will always be `object`, you can see the class hierarchy from that, e.g. `B.mro()[-2]` and `A.mro()[-2]` will both be `<class '__main__.A'>`

Comment: @kindall: No, `__class__` is its own obscure thing separate from `self.__class__`. It's the magic closure variable 0-argument `super` uses to determine what class it's being called from. It comes into existence if a method body lexically refers to `__class__` or `super`. It mostly exists to support 0-argument `super`, but you're allowed to use it directly if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Values retrieved from attributes don't remember where they came from.  You can't get the class from a method that you attached after the class definition.